# Create variable numbering observations with certain caracteristics R using tidyverse

Tags: r, tidyverse

I would like to assign a number to the days (events) were val>0,36 . I want to identify with an unique number any event that reach that rule (val> 0.36) preferably  using Tidyverse.

```
library(lubridate)
#create a df
date =as_date(ymd("2020-11-01"):ymd("2020-11-25"))
val = rnorm (25)

data = tibble(date, val)
```

Could anyone help me?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several ways to choose unique numbers to identify the events for which the threshold value is exceeded. Also, tidyverse might not be necessary - here is a Base R solution. It takes the index of the value in the `val` vector that exceeds the threshold as the unique ID. All other values that are below the threshold of 0.36 are coded as 0.

```
# (a) Initializing the 0s that later identify the non-events
data$flag <- rep(0, nrow(data)) 

# (b) identifying all values which exceed the threshold with the index
data$flag[which(val > 0.36)] <- which(val > 0.36)
```

**Output** (on my machine, randomly)

```
> data
# A tibble: 25 x 3
   date           val  flag
   <date>       <dbl> <dbl>
 1 2020-11-01  0.0231     0
 2 2020-11-02 -0.413      0
 3 2020-11-03  0.240      0
 4 2020-11-04 -0.465      0
 5 2020-11-05 -0.929      0
 6 2020-11-06 -0.409      0
 7 2020-11-07  0.598      7
 8 2020-11-08  0.970      8
 9 2020-11-09  1.25       9
10 2020-11-10  0.244      0
# ... with 15 more rows
```